# Swift - WebView is nil after in app purchase has completed

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, wkwebview, evaluatejavascript

I have a hybrid iOS app where I am passing data back and forth through javascript functionality. Everything is working correctly until the user has completed their in-app purchase. After they complete the purchase I am trying to call `webView.evaluateJavaScript` and `webView` is nil, thus throwing an error and not allowing me to complete the process.

Below is how I have the files setup.

**Main View Controller:**

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import Foundation
import StoreKit
import SafariServices

class MainViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler {
  var webView: WKWebView!
  ...

  override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    ...

    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
    webView.uiDelegate = self
  }

  ... 

  func finalizeIAPOrder() {
    print("webview: \(webView)"). // shows as nil
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("purchase_iap_completed()", completionHandler: nil)
  }

}
```

The user would access a website through `webView` and come to a page where they can purchase a product. The process for that works properly and eventually goes to my `PurchaseModel.swift` `finalizeProductOrder` action (shown below).

**PurchaseModel.swift**

```
import Foundation
import StoreKit

class PurchaseModel {

  ...

  fileprivate func finalizeProductOrder(_ product: SKProduct) {
    MainViewController().finalizeIAPOrder()

    // I have also tried the line below with the same nil error:
    // MainViewController().webView.evaluateJavaScript("purchase_iap_completed()", completionHandler: nil)
  }
}
```

Any help on this would be most appreciated. After I get the call going back to the main website I have the app fully working.

Thanks
Eric.

Comment: `MainViewController()` is initializing a new instance. You have to pass a reference to the showing instance of MainViewController to PurchaseModel.

Comment: Duh! didn't even notice this, @WilkoX is absolutely right

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @WilkoX for the help. What I ended up doing was the following:

**Main View Controller**

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import Foundation
import StoreKit
import SafariServices

class MainViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler {
  var webView: WKWebView!
  var purchaseModel: PurchaseModel?
  ...

  override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    purchaseModel = PurchaseModel(controller: self)
    ...

    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
    webView.uiDelegate = self
  }

  ... 

  func finalizeIAPOrder() {
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("purchase_iap_completed()", completionHandler: nil)
  }

}
```

**Purchase Model**

```
import Foundation
import StoreKit

class PurchaseModel {

  var controller: MainViewController

  init(controller: MainViewController) {
    self.controller = controller
  }
  ...

  fileprivate func finalizeProductOrder(_ product: SKProduct) {
    controller.finalizeIAPOrder()
  }
}
```

Also found help from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349050/pass-the-instance-as-a-reference-to-another-class-in-swift)